# Google Cloud Storage & Stackdriver Logging: how to read storage bucket logs with "gcloud"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, bucket, stackdriver

I am trying to read the server-side logs for the buckets in my Google Cloud Storage project via the `gcloud` command-line program (to solve an error I get using the storage client). 
It does not seem like the logs are available in the [Stackdriver Logging UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer).

So, first question: **are these logs available at all? If so, how do I access them?**

It *looks* like it should be possible via `gcloud`:

```
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:~ skyfer$ gcloud logging resource-descriptors list | grep -i storage
gcs_bucket                    A Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket.                                                                       
project_id,bucket_name,location
```

But using `gcloud logging read` e.g. like the following doesn't work:

```
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:~ skyfer$ gcloud logging read "resource.type=gcs_bucket AND logName=projects/my-project/logs/ AND textPayload:StorageException" --limit 10 --format json
[]
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name is missing the logs component. Expected the form projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/[ID]
```

So an important question is: **what is the syntax of the `ID`?** The documentation I have been able to find, e.g. [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) and [Available Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_index), doesn't seem to give the answer.

I have tried various formats and none have worked: they either return syntax errors or no results. I have also tried leaving out `ID` but that simply returns an empty list:

```
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:~ skyfer$ gcloud logging read "resource.type=gcs_bucket AND logName=projects/my-project/logs/my-bucket" --limit 10 --format json
[]
```

If I change the name of the bucket to a bucket that doesn't exist it doesn't seem to make a difference, indicating that the bucket name is not part of the id.

The bucket exists in Google Cloud Storage: verified both via the UI and `gsutil`:

```
Mortens-MacBook-Pro:~ skyfer$ gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/
gs://my-bucket/03ea8f19-8135-4101-a04a-aef3f19b0fdb/
gs://my-bucket/59e86a67-d035-4e4a-bc56-7c2da5e8c908/
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the logs are not available in the stackdriver.

There is 3 types of logging for google cloud storage.

**Access logs:** They provide information for all of the requests made on a specified bucket and are created hourly

**Daily storage logs:** They provide information about the storage consumption of that bucket for the last day.

**Cloud Audit Logging:** This gives you access logs of API operations performed in Cloud Storage, you can find more details about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs).

Your log files will have a specific format and you can find more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#downloading).

Once you figure the log file you want to download, you can download it via:

```
gsutil cp gs://<bucket_name>/<file_name>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I guess I am after the audit logs. I will look into this first thing Monday morning at work and hopefully get back to you with a big thumbs up.

Comment: I couldn't understand why I couldn't find any logs but it turned out I hadn't **enabled** logging on the bucket: `gsutil logging set on -b gs://logs-my-bucket -o access_log_ gs://my-bucket` and `gsutil acl ch -g cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:W gs://logs-my-bucket`. I will now wait an hour to see if any log files pop up in my new log bucket.

Comment: It worked! The logs are now available in "logs-my-bucket" - both available via the Google Cloud Storage UI and `gsutil cp gs://logs-my-bucket/access_log__usage_2018_03_19_09_00_00_00aada_v0 .`.

Answer (score 1):

you can list all the logs using below command
`gcloud logging logs list`

You can read a particular log using below command
`gcloud logging read <LOG_NAME>`